# Added new domain controllers but changes don't replicate to existing servers

Tags: active-directory

We have an on-premise domain with a few domain controllers. I recently added two new sites and domain controllers in those sites.

We're having some issues with replication from the new controllers where it can take hours to replicate or not at all.

All dcdiag tests pass. Repadmin /replsummary shows no errors.

I'm curious if it's something I need to do with "NTDS Settings" under Sites and Services as one of my new sites only shows one connection while my existing servers show all servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds this - we got this working by following the path this [Microsoft docs article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/troubleshoot-missing-sysvol-and-netlogon-shares) outlines.

Once we ran through these steps our replication resumed as expected.